# Estimating polymomial coefficient in R

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, polynomial, taylor-series

I used a Taylor series to expand log(1 - ax) so I could estimate the value of parameter 'a'.

The expansion becomes  -ax - a^2*x^2/2 - a^3*x^3/3 . . .

Now I need to estimate the parameter 'a' using regression and for simplicity I am only using the first 3 terms in the expansion.

The equation to be estimated becomes y ~ ax + a^2*x^2/2 + a^3*x^3/3 [I have absorbed the negative sign on the left hand side of the equation]

I wanted to ask if there is a way to estimate the coefficients a , a^2 and a^3 in the above equation, keeping in mind that all the three coefficients are powers of each other.

Is there a package in R for this?

Please do note that the Taylor series expansion was necessary as there are several other terms in the original equation which I haven't mentioned here.

Edit:

The original equation I have is:

Y ~ (1 - aX)(B^b)(C^c)(D^d)

In the above equation I have to estimate a,b,c,d, where a is to be estimated as aconstant while b,c and d as smooth splines.

So I have taken log on both side, which makes it:

log(Y) ~ log(1 - aX) + b*log(B) + c*log(C) + d*log(D)

If there is a better way to approach the entire equation, do mention.

Comment: It's no simplification--instead, it creates errors--to use the Taylor series instead of the function itself.  I would like to suggest you will get answers that are much more useful for your problem if you would ask us about the problem you actually have, rather than pursuing this approach.

Comment: Worth a read for the OP: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: even if there is a better way to approach the original problem, I would still like to know how to estimate coefficients when the coefficients are the power of each other.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the original equation I am trying to optimize.

Comment: One option would be using non-linear least squares to estimate a,b,c,d without doing any uncessary approximations. This algorithm is available via the `nls` function in R.

Comment: thanks Jarle. I will look into the nls package. Does this package allow for some terms to be estimated as splines like GAM package?

Comment: The two models (original and logged) are *different*: they (implicitly) posit different ways in which $Y$ might depart from the predicted values.  `nls`, for instance, could produce rather different parameter estimates for the two models, depending on the data. (BTW, `nls` is part of the base `R` distribution--it's not a package.)  Could you tell us anything about the distribution of the errors?  If not, we might be able to deduce which model is more appropriate by knowing what $Y$ represents and how it is measured.

Comment: thanks for the comment whuber. The error is log-normally distributed. The equation with error term becomes Y ~ (1 - aX)(B^b)(C^c)(D^d)(e) where e is the error term. Y is a non-negative integer valued variable.

Comment: How do you conclude the error is lognormal? If $Y$ is integer-valued, $e$  would not be lognormal.

Comment: the assumption that error is lognormal is made by the original paper which proposed the method. Of course because the data is count data, the distribution cannot be continuous, but I assume that approximating the distribution of error for count data as a continuous distribution shouldn't cause any problem. Am I wrong in assuming that?

Comment: thanks alot for all the help that has been provided. I haven't figured out the best way to solve the problem yet, but there are several directions which I have gotten which I will be pursuing. Firstly, as mentioned I will be looking at the nls function to optimize the function. Secondly, given that as suggested, log-normal distribution assumption might not the the best way, so I will be looking into how to estimate the parameters assuming a Poisson or NB distribution

Answer (score 1):

In this particular problem, $Y$ is linear in $a$, holding $b,c,d$ constant, and $\log Y$ is linear in $b,c,d$ holding $a$ constant. So we could probably use coordinate descent and least squares. Although, it's entirely possible that `nls` would be faster.

(Didn't test code)
Given vectors $Y,X,B,C,D$,

```
    #setup maximum iteration, tolerance, and initialize parameters
    max.iter <- 50
    tol <- 1e-4
    i <- a <- b <- c <- d <- 1
    log.y <- log(Y); log.b <- log(B)
    log.c <- log(C); log.d <- log(D)
    while(i <= max.iter){
      #a-update holdig b,c,d constant
        y.new <- Y/(B^b*C^c*D^d) - 1
        my.qr <- qr(-X)
        a <- qr.coef(my.qr, y.new)
      #b,c,d update holding a constant
        y.new <- log.y - log(1-a*X)
        my.qr <- qr(cbind(log.b, log.c, log.d))
        bcd <- qr.coef(my.qr, y.new)
        b <- bcd[1]
        c <- bcd[2]
        d <- bcd[3]
      #check convergence
      param.new <- c(a, bcd)
      if(norm(param.new-param.old) < tol) break
      else param.old <- param.new
      i <- i + 1
    }
    print(param.new)
```

Comment: Given additional information that the error is log-normal, this solves the wrong optimization problem.